# plotly layout - Y Axis range not working

Tags: python, layout, range, plotly, yaxis

i am trying to create a graph that will show a Scatter of the times i opened my computer. - i am using plotly offline. 
Y  = time, 
X  = date.

this works fine, but i can't make the Y axis to show all the hours of the day, but only the range of times that was in the data.

(for example, if i opened my computer only between 13:00-15:00 every day, the range of the Y axis will be from 13:00 to 15:00 only)

i am trying to show all the hours of the day on the Y axis by using the 'range' attribute in the layout, but it still doesn't work for me.

an example of my code:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from datetime import datetime, time

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# in the example i am using fabricated data. declaring the data:
time_data = [datetime(2017, 07, 28, 21, 37, 19), datetime(2017, 07, 29, 17, 11, 56), datetime(2017, 08, 01, 11, 15, 45), datetime(2017, 08, 02, 13, 54, 03)]
x_data = []
y_data = []

# creating the x-row data with dates only, and the y-row data with the time only
for row in time_data:
    x_data.append(row.date())
    y_data.append(datetime.combine(datetime(2017, 1, 1).date(), row.time))

#declaring the data for the graph
data = [Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data, name='Times On', mode='markers')]

# creating the hour range 
hours = []
for i in range (0, 24):
    hours.append(datetime(2017, 1, 1, i, 0, 0))

# declaring the Layout with the 'range' attribute, and Figure
layout = dict(title='Times On', xaxis=dict(type='date'), yaxis={'type': 'date', 'tickformat': '%H:%M', 'range': hours})
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# plotting
plot(figure_or_data=fig, filename='C:\Users\tototo\Desktop\Time-On')
```

does someone know what's the problem? any help would be blessed! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plotly seems to limit the axis based on the max and min values present in the corresponding axis. I tried each of the properties and came up with a solution.

**Approach:** The first one is generating what you need, but cant seem to get it to start at 12 in the midnight and end at 12 the next day.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
from datetime import datetime, time

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# in the example i am using fabricated data. declaring the data:
time_data = [datetime(2017, 7, 28, 21, 37, 19), datetime(2017, 7, 29, 17, 11, 56), datetime(2017,8, 1, 11, 15, 45), datetime(2017, 8, 2, 13, 54, 3)]
x_data = []
y_data = []

# creating the x-row data with dates only, and the y-row data with the time only
for row in time_data:
    x_data.append(row.date())
    y_data.append(str(datetime.combine(datetime(2017, 1, 1).date(), row.time())))

#declaring the data for the graph
data = [Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data, name='Times On', mode='markers')]

# creating the hour range 
hours = []
for i in range (0, 24):
    hours.append(datetime(2017, 1, 1, i, 0, 0))

# declaring the Layout with the 'range' attribute, and Figure
layout = dict(title='Times On', xaxis=dict(type='date'), yaxis={'type': 'date', 'tickformat': '%H:%M', 
                                                                'nticks': 30, 'tick0': hours[0],
                                                                'range': [hours[0], hours[len(hours)-1]],
                                                                'autorange': False})
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# plotting
iplot(figure_or_data=fig)
```

The above code is giving me the output:

[image]

Comment: This code actually works for me! It shows me the graph from 00:00 at the bottom :) thank you very much!